# Measuring time dilation

Tags: relativity, time-dilation

After watching [a certain recent film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_(film)), I started wondering whether it would be possible to create a watch (or, more likely due to the sizes of the components, a clock) capable of measuring one's time dilation relative to where the watch was built (or reset, perhaps).

The setup:

- Three perpendicular load cells $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ with one end fixed and the other attached to a known mass. From these three, which form a vector, you can calculate the strength of the local gravitational force. For obvious reasons, this watch would only work with near-zero accelerations.
- For each small time step $\Delta t$, measure it according to local time, dilate accordingly, and update the display.

Is there any reason why this watch wouldn't work, given my near-zero acceleration assumption? And can anyone think of a design that would work even with acceleration?

Since you wouldn't be able to tell (with any instruments) if you were in a spaceship accelerating through empty space at 1g or sitting on the ground, my intuition is that you wouldn't be able to make this distinction. However, there's likely something I'm not thinking of, such as a term that cancels in the equations that means you don't have to differentiate between gravity/acceleration.

Comment: Two coments. One: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment. Two: time dilation is always measured relative some other observer; it is not a property of a single system but one of *comparison* between systems.

Comment: Third comment: Gravitational time dilation is a function of difference in gravitational potential rather than gravitational force (which isn't a true force in general relativity)

Comment: @dmckee right; in my question I mention "relative to where the watch was built (or reset, perhaps)". I'm also familiar with Hafele-Keating. Perhaps I should rephrase my question, "Is it possible to build a watch which, no matter where the user is, gives the current time in another frame of reference?" As much as I hate to keep going back to _Interstellar_, would it be possible to create a watch that Cooper could wear on the water planet that would tell him how much time had passed for Romily?

Comment: @DavidHammen Thanks. Are you implying that it would be impossible to build such a watch then? If so, then that would be a great answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The device you describe sounds like an accelerometer, but time dilation is not related to the force you experience, whether it's a gravitational force or a force due to acceleration.

Where the time dilation is due to curved spacetime, i.e. gravity, the time dilation between two clocks is related to the gravitational potential energy difference between the clocks. NB *potential* not *force*.

Where the time dilation is due to relative motion in flat spacetime the time dilation is calculated by comparing the proper time elapsed for the two clocks. This is basically caused by their relative motion not their relative acceleration (though I suppose in principle you could integrate the acceleration to get the relative velocity).

Comment: In flat spacetime I think it shouldn't be too hard to calculate your velocity relative to some "initial" frame given your subsequent proper accelerations (assuming your accelerometer was very accurate), in a curved spacetime this would probably be more tricky, I think you'd have to know the curvature of all regions you might pass through in advance.